# How to create Cloudfront Console Alarm Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Create a cloudwatch alarm:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "cloudfront-500-errors" {
  alarm_name          = "${var.ENVIRONMENT_NAME}-AWS-CloudFront-High-5xx-Error-Rate"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = 1
  metric_name         = "5xxErrorRate"
  namespace           = "AWS/Cloudfront"
  period              = 60
  statistic           = "Average"
  threshold           = 5
  treat_missing_data  = "notBreaching"
  alarm_actions       = [aws_sns_topic.my-sns-topic.arn]
  actions_enabled     = true

  dimensions = {
    DistributionId = aws_cloudfront_distribution.this.id
    Region         = "Global"
  }
}
```

I can create an alarm for cloudwatch in terraform, but how do I get the alarm here in "Cloudfront" ?

[image]

Comment: I guess "terraform apply" completed successfully. and in this case, although this is a rather silly assumption, but still check the selected region in the browser

Comment: Correct region in browser. The alarm exists in cloudwatch, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to show up in cloudfront alarms, unless i manually create it using the console gui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is that, this UI is really just a link to the cloudwatch metrics. The real issue is my namespace was:

```
 namespace           = "AWS/Cloudfront"
```

and it needed to be :

```
 namespace           = "AWS/CloudFront"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, Cloudfront cloudwatch metrics are only available in us-east-1.

Therefore, be sure to have an aws provider for that region set up and point the alarm to it.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "cloudfront-500-errors" {
  provider            = aws.useast1
  alarm_name          = "training_cloudfrotn_alarm"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = 1
  metric_name         = "4xxErrorRate"
  namespace           = "AWS/CloudFront"
  period              = 60
  statistic           = "Average"
........
}
```

and the provider:

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  alias  = "useast1"
}
```

[how it looks in Clodufront's GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eltpk.png)